# PayPal API 2 buy now destination

Tags: api, paypal

I want to create an online shop, but I have one thing do to. When a client buy an item, I want to deposit 75% of the price in one PayPal account and 25% in another PayPal account. How can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

Adaptive Payments would be how you would do this. Adaptive Payments manages the payment between the sender and one or more receivers. You are the application owner, (just like a merchant that owns a website, the owner of a widget on a social networking site, or the provider of a payment application on cell phones).

Your application is the caller of Adaptive Payments API operations.

To use Adaptive Payments, you must have a PayPal business account. Senders and receivers can have any PayPal account type. Senders and receivers are not required to have PayPal accounts initially; but the sender is prompted to create an account before a payment can be completed, and a receiver must create an account to receive the funds after the payment completes.

In some cases, you may be both the application owner and a receiver. If you are the owner of a website, you are also the receiver of payments from the senders who are your customers.

Adaptive Payments provides several methods of payment: simple, parallel, and chained payments. Each method of payment is called with the Pay API; the payment method is determined by how the request is structured.

Simple payments allow a sender to send a single payment to a single receiver. This is the traditional way that payments are made. Your website could use an Adaptive Payments checkout flow for transferring money from a sale from your customer’s PayPal account to your own account. 
Parallel payments allow a sender to send a single payment that is split directly among 2 to 6 receivers. Your application might be a shopping cart and allow a buyer to pay for items from several merchants with one payment. Your shopping cart distributes the payment to merchants that actually provided the items. PayPal then deducts money from the sender’s account and deposits it in the receivers’ accounts. 
Chained payments allow a sender to send a single payment to a primary receiver. The primary receiver keeps part of the payment and pays secondary receivers the remainder. For example, your application could be an online travel agency that handles bookings for airfare, hotel reservations, and car rentals. The sender sees only you as the primary receiver. You allocate the payment for your commission and the actual cost of services provided by other receivers. PayPal then deducts money from the sender’s account and deposits it in both your account and the secondary receivers’ accounts. 
To apply for adaptive payment for the live site and get an app ID for Adaptive Payments integration, send an application to our app review team.

You can send your application by going to this site: https://apps.paypal.com/user/my-account/applications. Please be as detailed as possible when submitting the application.

For integration steps and better understanding, review this documentation:

https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/adaptive-payments/integration-guide/APIntro/